# Attribute access time very long with DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to understand why Dataframe attributes access time seems so long (often 100 x slower vs other objects). An example :

```
In [37]: df=pd.DataFrame([])

In [38]: a=np.array([])

In [39]: %timeit df.size
28 µs ± 4.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [40]: %timeit a.size
136 ns ± 9.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Hmmm, so question is why is pandas slowier as numpy?

Comment: I don't know. no job done here,  Just attribute access... Perhaps the difference is at python level ?

Comment: I think each function is different, first call [`numpy.ndarray.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) and last [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)

Comment: This seems to be more about transpose being slower for DataFrames than arrays; not so much about attribute access in general. `df.T` is necessarily more involved than calling `a.T`, even for empty collections. Both transposes create new objects, but DataFrames are more complicated objects to build and validation checks must happen (even for "empty" frames).

Comment: @ Alex Riley : I agree this is not the best example. I change the post with size attribute.

Comment: Even though you changed the example, Alex's answer still applies.  A pandas dataframe is inherently more complex than a numpy array so practically every time you try to do a comparable action it will be faster in numpy.  Hence, for times where you need speed and don't need the extra features of pandas, use numpy.  Also, it's very easy to temporarily drop down to numpy with `.values` so efficient workflows often involve a mix of pandas and numpy